# eager load and empty queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to put my catalog in cache by team. 
Price may vary by team.
But if the price is not set for a product I need to send the "default" team value", and can't find an easy way to do this.

```
$teams = Team::all();

foreach ($teams as $team) {

    $teamId = $team->id;

    $catalog = Cache::rememberForever('catalog-' . $team->id, function () use ($teamId) {

        $catalog = Category::with(['products.prices' => function ($q) use ($teamId) {
            $q->where("team_id", $teamId); // and if no result $q->where("team_id",1);
        }])->all();

        return $catalog;
    });
}
```

I was searching with queries like $q->whereNotExist, but I can't find a way to do it correctly. They may be some other way to do this via Product or Price model (and mutator), but I also stuck here.

Thank you.

Comment: What type of relationship is `prices`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir  prices is a many to one with products.

Comment: You want one or the other right?  You may have to execute your initial query without the `all` so you can use the `count` method, and if no results, create a new query with the default value.

Comment: @adam But with count, I will get result. In this case I need to count foreach categories -> product -> prices. That may be a solution but not very clean.

Comment: You won’t get a result with `->count()` called on the query object.  This method will count the results of the query.